# HTML/CSS: does copy-paste ammendment work on Android and iOS?

Tags: css, mobile

...Unfortunately I forget what this is called and I can't find it on google; please tell me so I can edit this OP.

Some websites use a neat feature of CSS whereby any text you copy from the site actually copies to the clipboard what you selected PLUS an amendment containing something like a  copyright notice and the original URL.

My question: does this feature work on Android and iOS (and mobile browsing in general)?